# sending file via BlueTooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

actually I'm developing a free app which needs to share itself via bluetooth when a certain button is pressed and I have used this code(I try to get the file from sd-card) :

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
        }

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is turned off, please enable it to proceed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            File sourceFile = findFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"E-charge.apk");
            Intent intent = new Intent();  
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
            intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(sourceFile) );  
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

and here's the piece of manifest related to the activity that this button is in it :

```
<activity
        android:name=".main.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:host="*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern="*.*\\.apk" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

However when I press the button(in android 2.3.5) it gives me options to send via e-mail only and not bluetooth, so may I ask for your help to make it work?

also I have added permissions for bluetooth guys so that's not the case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change the following line :

> intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");

to

```
intent.setType("application/zip");
```